# Is $\exists x \forall y \exists z$ $(y > x \rightarrow y = xz)$ true or false?

Tags: logic

I'm given $\exists x \forall y \exists z$ $(y > x \rightarrow y = xz)$ where $x, y, z \in \mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$.

If $y=0$ there's no $x$ such that $y>x$, but $z=0$ makes the implication be $False \rightarrow True$, which is True.

So this means the whole thing still true?

If it is false I have to write it's negative. I think it would be $\forall x \exists y \forall z (y>x \wedge y\not=xz)$. Is it right?

Comment: So... you have argued that if $y=0$, then regardless of what $x$ and $z$ are, then the implication is true. That seems accurate. But that does not tell you that the full sentence is true; at best, it tells you that setting $y=0$ will not disprove it.

Comment: Is there a natural number $x$ with the property that every natural number $y>x$ is a multiple of $x$?

Comment: The key to these problems isn't symbolic manipulation, it's understanding intuitively what the symbolic statements are saying.

Comment: So I don't have to look to every $y$, just the $y>x$ for the $x$ I choose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x=1$. Then for all $y>x$, there exists a $z$, namely $z=y$ such that $y=1(z)$.

Comment: And if $y=1$, using $z=1$ then the implication is $false \rightarrow true$ which is true. So as Arturo Magidin said, does not disprove it. Right?

Comment: Yes, this does not disprove it.